# How to get values of a column by SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I want to get the values of a column by SQLAlchemy, I know I can do like this:

For example:

```
result = db.session.query(User.id).all()
```

but the result is a set of list.

```
result = [(1),(2),(3).........]
result = [i[0] for i in result] // how to omit this step?
```

but I hope to get a list([1,2,3....]) or a set(1,2,3) directly. Anyone has good idea?

Answer (score -1):

It seems there is no approach in SQLAlchemy